# Powershell scripting in a foreach from 14 column array syntax

Tags: powershell

I use the #Debug to output what is in @table and it has data (see DATASAMPLE1, it is just one row).  When I run it throws the error #MyError.  When I comment out the foreach loop, it runs without error.

What is wrong with my syntax?

MyError:

```
Cannot index into a null array.
At C:\Duane\Project\PowerShell\WebPerformancequery2.ps1:127 char:10
+             <td>$($dataitem[13])</td>
+                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NullArray
```

Code:

```
#$Query
    $query = "
exec p_TopSlowestRunningQueries @DaysIntoPast=7, @SvrNameIN = 'PRD'
"

#$Query
$table = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $DDServer -Database $DBDatabase -Query $Query -QueryTimeout 600

#Debug
Write-Verbose ($table | Out-String) -Verbose

#PutIntoWebPage
 $Outputreport = "<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 

    <meta charset=""utf-8"">

    <meta name=""viewport"" content=""initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=2.0"">

    <title>Central DB - Last date DatabaseRestored</title>
    <link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href=""../servers/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css""> 
    <link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href=""../servers/resources/syntax/shCore.css""> 
    <link rel=""stylesheet"" type=""text/css"" href=""../servers/resources/demo.css""> 
    <style type=""text/css"" class=""init""> 


    </style>
    <script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"" src=""./excellentexport-1.4/ExcellentExport.js""></script>         
    <script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"" src=""../servers/media/js/jquery.js""></script> 
    <script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"" src=""../servers//media/js/jquery.dataTables.js""></script> 
    <script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"" src=""../servers/resources/syntax/shCore.js""></script> 
    <script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"" src=""../servers/resources/demo.js""></script> 
    <script type=""text/javascript"" language=""javascript"" class=""init""> 

`$(document).ready(function() { 
    `$('#example').DataTable({
    ""iDisplayLength"": -1,
    ""order"": [[ 2, 1, ""asc"" ]],
    ""aLengthMenu"": [[10, 25, 50, 100, -1], [10, 25, 50, 100, ""All""]]
});
} ); 
    </script> 

</head> 



<body class=""dt-example"">
    <div class=""container""> 

                <h2>Top Prod - Perfomance Query Issues</h2> 
                <p>The inventory gathered by powershell output as of $date &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <a download=""somedata.xlsx"" href=""#"" onclick=""return ExcellentExport.excel(this, 'example', 'Sheet Name Here');"">Export table to Excel</a>  &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<a download=""somedata.csv"" href=""#"" onclick=""return ExcellentExport.csv(this, 'example');"">Export table to CSV</a>  (Does not work with IE)</p>


<table id=""example"" class=""display"" cellSpacing=""0"" width=""100%"">
       <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>SvrName</th>
                <th>DatabaseName</th>
                <th>Count</th>
                <th>AverageDuration</th>
                <th>TotalDuration</th>
                <th>AverageCPU</th>
                <th>AverageReads</th>
                <th>AverageWrites</th>
                <th>ApplicationName</th>
                <th>HostName</th>
                <th>FirstStartTime</th>
                <th>LastEndTime</th>
                <th>StatementType</th>
                <th>StatementText</th>
             </tr>
        </thead>

        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>SvrName</th>
                <th>DatabaseName</th>
                <th>Count</th>
                <th>AverageDuration</th>
                <th>TotalDuration</th>
                <th>AverageCPU</th>
                <th>AverageReads</th>
                <th>AverageWrites</th>
                <th>ApplicationName</th>
                <th>HostName</th>
                <th>FirstStartTime</th>
                <th>LastEndTime</th>
                <th>StatementType</th>
                <th>StatementText</th>
            </tr>
       </tfoot>

       <tbody>
"


foreach ($dataitem in $table.Rows)
{
$Outputreport += "<tr>
            <td data-search=""$($dataitem[0])"">$($dataitem[0])</td>
            <td>$($dataitem[1])</td>
            <td>$($dataitem[2])</td>
            <td>$($dataitem[3])</td>
            <td>$($dataitem[4])</td>
            <td>$($dataitem[5])</td>
            <td>$($dataitem[6])</td>
            <td>$($dataitem[7])</td>
            <td>$($dataitem[8])</td>
            <td>$($dataitem[9])</td>
            <td>$($dataitem[10])</td>
            <td>$($dataitem[11])</td>
            <td>$($dataitem[12])</td>
            <td>$($dataitem[13])</td>
        </tr>
        "
}

$Outputreport += "</tbody>

    </table>

</body> 
</html> "
```

Data:

```
DATASAMPLE1
SvrName         : XXXX01
DatabaseName    : Merlin7
Count           : 1
AverageDuration : 10197.00
TotalDuration   : 
AverageCPU      : 657.00
AverageReads    : 1521.00
AverageWrites   : 0.00
ApplicationName : .Net SqlClient Data Provider
HostName        : XXXXX02
FirstStartTime  : 8/7/2019 3:50:23 AM
LastEndTime     : 8/7/2019 3:50:33 AM
StatementType   : 0
StatementText   : SELECT StatMan([SC0], [SC1], [SC2], [SC3], [SC4], [SC5], [SC6], [SC7], [SC8], [SC9], [SB0000]) FROM (SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT 
                  [SC0], [SC1], [SC2], [SC3], [SC4], [SC5], [SC6], [SC7], [SC8], [SC9], step_direction([SC0]) over (order by NULL) AS [SB0000]  
                  FROM (SELECT [IsReoccurring] AS [SC0], [ClaimsIncluded] AS [SC1], [iHistorical] AS [SC2], [DroppedYear] AS [SC3], [HCC_MOR] 
                  AS [SC4], [CoreClient_WK] AS [SC5], [Client_WK] AS [SC6], [MaxTrump] AS [SC7], [FileID_WK] AS [SC8], [IsEDPS] AS [SC9] FROM 
                  [dbo].[DroppedHCCReport] TABLESAMPLE SYSTEM (9.529627e+000 PERCENT) WITH (READUNCOMMITTED) ) AS _MS_UPDSTATS_TBL_HELPER ORDER 
                  BY [SC0], [SC1], [SC2], [SC3], [SC4], [SC5], [SC6], [SC7], [SC8], [SC9], [SB0000] ) AS _MS_UPDSTATS_TBL  OPTION (MAXDOP 1)
```

Comment: I've tried to split the supplied files from one code block into several pieces, for clarity. If I have not split them correctly (particularly the middle one) then please edit again.

Comment: do all of your rows have 14 properties/columns?

Comment: yes.  All rows have 14 columns.  It is a select from a table in a database.

Comment: How may times does the `foreach ($dataitem in $table.Rows)` loop execute? I would add `Write-Host $dataitem.length` inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the answer.  This is awsome, Powershell that creates a web page to publish the slowest running queries for developers!

```
foreach ($dataitem in $table)
{

$Outputreport += "<tr>
            <td data-search=""$($dataitem.SvrName)"">$($dataitem.SvrName)</td>
            <td>$($dataitem.DatabaseName)</td>
            <td>$($dataitem.Count)</td>
            <td>$($dataitem.AverageDuration)</td>
            <td>$($dataitem.TotalDuration)</td>
            <td>$($dataitem.AverageCPU)</td>
            <td>$($dataitem.AverageReads)</td>
            <td>$($dataitem.AverageWrites)</td>
            <td>$($dataitem.ApplicationName)</td>
            <td>$($dataitem.HostName)</td>
            <td>$($dataitem.FirstStartTime)</td>
            <td>$($dataitem.LastEndTime)</td>
            <td>$($dataitem.StatementType)</td>
            <td>$($dataitem.StatementText)</td>
        </tr>
        "
}
```